# Jacobi Triple product cases

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Hello I want some guidance how can I prove these identities of Jacobi Tripple Product

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{2n^2+n}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{2n})^2}{(1-q^n)}$$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n^2}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-(-q)^n)}{(1+(-q)^n)}$$

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{n(n+1)}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(1-q^{4n})}{(1-q^{4n-2})}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with the triple product identity

> $$\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty z^n q^{n^2} = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + zq^{2n-1})(1 + z^{-1}q^{2n-1}).$$

1. Replacing $q$ by $q^2$, then setting $z = q$, we obtain

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty q^{2n^2+n} &= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n})(1 + q^{4n-1})(1 + q^{4n-3})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n})(1 + q^{2n-1})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n-1})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + q^n)\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{(1 - q^{2n})^2}{1 - q^n}.
\end{align}

2. Setting $z = 1$, we get

\begin{align}\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty q^{n^2} &= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n-1})(1 + q^{2n-1})\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)\prod_{n\, \text{odd}}^\infty (1 + q^n)\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 + q^n}{1 + q^{2n}}\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - q^{2n}}{(1 - q^n)(1 + q^{2n})}\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)\prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - q^{2n}}{(1 - q^{2n})(1 - q^{2n-1})(1 + q^{2n})}\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - (-q)^n}{(1 - q^{2n-1})(1 + q^{2n})}\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - (-q)^n}{1 + (-q)^n}.
\end{align}

3. Setting $z = q$ results in

\begin{align}\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty q^{n^2 + n} &= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n-2})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n})\prod_{n = 2}^\infty (1 + q^{2n-2})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n}) \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 + q^{2n})\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n}) \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - q^{4n}}{1 - q^{2n}}\\
& = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{4n}) \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - q^{4n}}{(1 - q^{4n})(1 - q^{4n-2})}\\
&= \prod_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1 - q^{4n}}{1 - q^{4n-2}}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks you.    
but I can not able to understand the second step of identity 2.

Comment: It follows from $$\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - q^{2n})(1 + q^{2n-1}) = \prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)$$ and $$\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 + q^{2n-1}) = \prod_{n\, \text{odd}} (1 + q^n).$$

Comment: The first product identity I mentioned results from breaking the product $\prod_{n = 1}^\infty (1 - (-q)^n)$ into even and odd parts.

Comment: ohh thanks now I understand

Comment: Yes why not ...